# How to dial-in conference in nexmo?

Tags: tokbox, vonage, conference

I am using this repo:
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-nexmo-sip/tree/master/Dial-In-Conference

Bought nexmo virtual number and created new tokbox app.Set up all credentials. Changed only voicename and text in server.js. For local testing purposes I am using tunnel through ngrok, so in nexmo dashboard I've put my actual ngrok url for endpoints with ending eg. /nexmo-answer and /nexmo-events.
When I start app and go to new room eg. room/2 I can see, my app is working, camera and microphone works perfectly also my coworker can go to my link through tunnel and we can talk.

The problem is that nobody can dial into our conference. Anyone calling can hear welcome message and pin prompt, after inputting correct pin, the phone apparently connects (doesn't disconnect automatically) but we can't hear or send any sound. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my error. App needs to dial out into nexmo's virtual number's room.